# EOL Notice: Hardy, Oneiric, Lucid (desktop) are now End of Life

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

This is a reminder/notice regarding now-EOL releases.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives are officially **end of life** as of today on May 9th, 2013:

- Hardy Heron (8.04, all currently-still-supported (server) editions)
- Lucid Lynx (10.04, Desktop)
- Oneiric Ocelot (11.10, all versions)

As of today (May 9, 2013), new questions regarding the above may need to be considered **off-topic**.  Old questions that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This can be confirmed on the **[official Ubuntu Wiki page that lists all current, development, and end-of-lifed releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)**

Comment: I still have my original installation media for 8.04. Can I really be that old?

Comment: @NathanOsman I have 8.04 installation media too.  :P

Comment: @NathanOsman I have it too :)

Comment: You can burn a new 8.04 CD.

Comment: I have media for Ubuntu 4.04 (Breezy).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lets hold on for a second with destroying old questions. Doing anything in mass always has me a bit concerned.

What I'd like to propose instead is do the following:

All questions still open with those releases be closed as off-topic with a similar comment of:

> This release of Ubuntu is no longer supported and is now End Of Life (EOL).

With links to supporting documentation.

That was the easy part. I'm conflicted as to what we should do with old questions that are already answered. Honestly we should first find the version specific questions with extremely high views and amend the top of the question with a post notice about upgrading and that these are now EOL. But I think, for the most part, old questions with these versions that don't get a lot of views and are already answered are just Okay. Going commando on them is only going to disrupt the current moderation process for users as no one really be focusing on the current queues and just waste votes and hunting for these demonized low hanging fruit. As they pop up (get bumped with new answers and the such) we should just close them then.

I would also like to point out that not EVERY SINGLE QUESTION MARKED WITH THAT VERSION ACTUALLY PERTAINS TO THAT VERSION AND EACH SHOULD BE SCRUTINIZED BEFORE BLINDLY PASSING JUDGEMENT. A decent amount of these can just be updated or have the version removed and still be relevant to today's releases.

I'll try to bake a data query later tonight to help identify potential questions.

Comment: Never said anything about destroying old questions, but as for new questions specifically related to the releases mentioned in this thread (after the May 9th EOL date), closing as either Too Localized or Offtopic is still the acceptable course of action, right?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Yes, offtopic and closed immediately :)

Comment: I've agreed with all the statements in your answer, and have marked it as accepted, but we may have to change that if we have more suitable answers.

Comment: I don't think old, answered questions should ever be closed. I find a lot of useful information in really old questions. using ls in 8.04 and 13.04 is exactly the same, for example. New questions on those versions should be closed though. No need to spend time helping people install old versions of lilo on 20G hard drives.

Comment: Closing or Deleting all questions does not help. Yeah sure, the ones that do not have an answer yet, yes (After carefully reading them and maybe marking them as duplicate of a similar but yet still supported question). The old ones should be left there for anyone that still uses an old version to find answers.

Answer (score 10):

Flamethrower -  [image]

Gatling Gun -  [image]

Backpack full of grenades - [image]

Red Bull - [image]

Rail Gun - [image]

Street of Rage + Double Dragon fighting Techniques - [image]

Mod Power - [image]

Bubblegum - ....

Bubblegum - ....

Bubblegum - ..???

Bubblegum - ????

**I have come here to kick ass and chew bubblegum... and I'm all out of bubblegum**

Comment: *hands stick of gum*

Comment: @TheLordofTime what might you be talking about. I don't see nothing wrong (Troll ;) )

Answer (score 6):

Just to tell everyone, I have changed all the upcoming EOL releases' tag wikis to update the EOL date.