# Request to Un-duplicate

Tags: support

Could I ask an administrator to remove the flag that says this is a duplicate please:
  https://askubuntu.com/q/355377/93794

I edited it this morning (12hrs ago) to explain why it is not a duplicate (at least not of the linked question), though the linked question was an idea worth trying. I wasn't sure if I then needed to do something to get it changed back, but I've just been informed that the duplicate flag is stopping someone posting an answer, so I thought I'd try posting here.
(Answers in comments on StackExchange sites is one of pet peeves :-)

Thanks!!

Comment: While I agree that it's probably not the right thing to dupe-close it against, 10.04 is off-topic because it's so old.

Answer (score 5):

This question was incorrectly duplicated.  As @Oli has commented, we treat desktop-based applications on 10.04 as off-topic.  The only questions for 10.04 that are on-topic are server-based questions.

- [EOL Notice: Hardy, Oneiric, Lucid (desktop) are now End of Life](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6645/eol-notice-hardy-oneiric-lucid-desktop-are-now-end-of-life)

Thus, in this case, I've reopened and then closed again to the off-topic reason.

Comment: Thanks, that is a clear explanation, and closing it as off-topic is at least accurate. (I disagree that it should be off-topic, though: the oldubuntu site means I can, and will, be running 10.04 desktop for at least another year.)

Comment: @DarrenCook you can discuss the EOL question handling policy [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again) if you want, because Meta is nice in that you can voice your disagreements and suggestions to fix things here and the community will vote on it.  (however, the decision on handling EOL questions that was quoted in the EOL notice has been the policy since 12.04 was released, so it's unlikely to be changed quickly, if at all)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why instead of EOL was closed as Duplicated, but in both cases it makes you upgrade your system with the question that was marked as duplicated.

> To the people insisting I upgrade Ubuntu: my question is how to run something later than Chromium 25 on Ubuntu 10.04. "Impossible because xxx" is an answer. "Upgrade Ubuntu" is not.

Why Upgrade Ubuntu is not? At the end of the day you want to run latest Chromium and we are telling you what you need to reach that goal. If we start to detail all dependencies that you need to run the latest on the obsolete, what problems you might find, a **long etc.** it will not end. So we told you in comments *Ubuntu is too old, hence you couldn't expect to run the latest software on it* and direct you to how you can solve the "old" problem and run Chromium.

We are telling you exactly what is the problem (without boring anyone with technical details) and how to solve it in a single step. Why insist in trying to get an explanation of something that might not be of your interest (that I presume is running Chromium whatever it takes) taking us time.

The community is the one that decides the best method to help you, and we considered that we are helping you to do what you wanted to do. Unless you edit your question and explain what exactly is your goal, as the question is that is the only path to take.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The question was quite clear (IMHO!) that it was "is it possible to run a version of Chromium after 25 on Ubuntu 10.04". The answer has absolutely nothing to do with whether Ubuntu 10.04 desktop is end-of-life or not. The answer appears to be "no, Chromium 26 requires a later version of glibc than Ubuntu 10.04 supports". But no-one has been allowed to post that answer.