# EOL Notice: Raring (13.04) is now past End of Life

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that have reached end of life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives are officially **end of life** as of January 27, 2014:

- Raring 13.04

New questions regarding the above posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**.  Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed on the **[official Ubuntu Wiki page that lists all current, development, and end-of-lifed releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)**

<sub>The date "January 27, 2014" was established in an IRC discussion with the release team.  It has been confirmed in [this announcement email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-January/000178.html).</sub>

---

**Confirmation of this End of Life date was published to the Security Announcements mailing list, [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2014-January/002382.html) confirming that Raring 13.04 is now End of Life.**

---

**Please make note that this is the first time that we will have a release EOL before an older release other than LTSes.  12.10 is not EOL-ing at this time, and has an EOL date of April 2013.**

Comment: This post does NOT state that old questions should be deleted, nor does it say old questions regarding an EOL release should be closed or nuked.  It simply serves as a reminder / notice that the 13.04 release of Ubuntu will be considered End of Life for new posts as of January 27, 2014 (give or take, depending on when the release team officially announces 13.04 is EOL)

Comment: Well that was  alarmingly fast.

Comment: @Oli indeed.  It went by quickly.  Still, it never hurts to have the EOL reminders, right?

Comment: Wow, seems like the versions are going by much faster. Makes sense, because they are, but Canonical sure is pushing this upgrade cycle eh?

Comment: January 27th seems confirmed.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yep, it does, I was gonna link to that announcement.  :)

Comment: @RPi they changed the support cycle to be 9 months for non-LTS starting with 13.04.  Not sure if they're pushing the upgrade cycles or not, I don't remember the reasoning behind the change.

Comment: Reason: http://askubuntu.com/q/270529/169736

Comment: @chaskes I think that's better suited for another discussion thread in meta, and not on this thread which isn't about 14.04

Comment: @chaskes this thread is not the thread about how to handle the upgrade track once 14.04 is out, this thread serves solely as a reminder to people that they should consider reminding people using 13.04 (and asking questions about it) to upgrade to 13.10 or some similar action before the EOL date.  It also acts as a reminder that, per policy, on January 27, 2014, any new 13.04 Raring questions will be offtopic because of the policy for EOL releases (see the help center), save for "How do I upgrade from Raring to `$some_release`".

Comment: So a user still using 13.04 after Jan 27 is out of luck even if all they want is to ask a question? I suggest that after the magic date valid questions are still valid even if Canonical is no longer supporting the release?

Comment: @haziz we had this discussion before about how we treat EOL releases [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6645/eol-notice-hardy-oneiric-lucid-desktop-are-now-end-of-life).  Per [Oli's answer to the meta about handling EOL releases](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7459/10616) we came to an agreement to follow the support timetables.  The basis of closing these questions and such is to encourage people to NOT use unsupported software and use supported releases that continue to get security updates.

Comment: I'm sorry but I find this ridiculous. Fair enough if Canonical doesn't want to support it, but what is wrong with asking the community a question? Fine encourage people to upgrade, but why make the ultimatum - no one is *allowed* to help you if you are using software that is not supported by a company

Comment: @Anake discuss it in another meta thread.  Note that there's already consensus as WHY We don't support old EOL releases here: because of old, not supported, insecure software

Comment: I hope in future releases won't EOL before next release comes out !lol.

Comment: @aditya this page is useful to determine EOL dates: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: You have an incorrect EOL date for 12.10, which is confusing to read.

Comment: @TRiG this is a 13.04 post, not a 12.10 one, you'd need to provide context in a separate meta thread.  Regardless 12.10 is long dead so... not sure how much it matters

Comment: Last paragraph in bold, you mention 12.10 with an implication that it has a later EOL, but give a date that's earlier, which is confusing. Old and irrelevant, yes, but I came across it just now in casual browsing of the site, and was puzzled till I realised that you had the year wrong.

Comment: @TRiG there was a separatr 12.10 EOL notice.  There was no need to update this one.  Move on and let historical posts like this one just die ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today, January 27, 2014, is the day that 13.04 Raring reached End of Life.

While this means **new** questions (stressing the **new**) about 13.04 are off topic, older questions (both answered and unanswered) that were around before the EOL date should not be closed or deleted.

**This is done here with the consensus of the moderators which is that the primary reason for is not supporting EOL releases is because those versions no longer receive updates or security support, and you should not use those versions because of the lack of security updates.  This is not just my opinion, but has reached some consensus here on meta in other threads.**

Also note that 13.10 is still supported. as is 12.10.

---

#### If you have an issue with how we handle EOL releases, you need to bring up this issue in a different thread.  This thread here is NOT a valid thread for arguing against the EOL policies.  This thread is simply a notice that, in accordance with the CURRENT moderation policies, these questions are offtopic because of the End of Life date.

We already have a thread that came to a generally-accepted stance regarding EOL releases, and Oli, one of our moderators, stated this point very well, summing up why we don't support EOL releases [at this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7459/10616).  To quote [Oli♦](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/449/oli):

> "Running fine" is hard to swallow given everybody who asks a question
> has a problem.
>
> #### We should close EOL questions because as a community of both Ubuntu users and internet denizens, we should *want* people to stop using
>
> unsupported software.
>
> Many years ago I... Well let's just say I had more than a passing
> interest in computer security. Something that I saw again and again
> and again is that software running on the internet without updates is
> software that gets hacked and cracked wide open.
>
> We should care because it's that computer that goes on to infect
> another dozen unpatched computers, send out spam and DDOS networks you
> care about.
>
> Lucid (10.04) is off-topic on the desktop because its software is now
> lagging behind. Firefox is seven months old and that means known
> security flaws that are being exploited in the wild. **Desktop 10.04
> users are a liability to the internet. We all have a personal interest
> in them upgrading.**
>
> I don't think it's unreasonable cost that people have to use supported
> software to get support and by enforcing that through closing
> questions, we show users that we won't help them run dangerous
> software.

This is why we are not supporting EOL releases.  We may not be a medium of support run by Canonical, but there's a LOT of good reasons why they don't support EOL releases, and a lot of those reasons apply here, still, including the fact that the old systems are RIDDLED with unfixed security bugs that will not be getting fixed.  Because of that, users should NOT be using old, unsupported software, after Canonical EOL's the software.

As well, the comments on [Oli♦](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)'s answer are important and also need to be known:

> Thanks for the feedback Oli. I still feel this is a Q&A site. Its
> purpose is to allow volunteers to answer other people's questions. All
> I am saying is people should be allowed to ask questions about the
> version of Ubuntu they are using, and people who have answers to those
> questions should be allowed to give them. - [Darren
> Cook](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/93794/darren-cook)
>
> That sentiment would have us supporting 90% of Ubuntu and Debian
> spin-offs. I do agree that it's nice to be helpful but it's more than
> just a scope issue here. It's dangerous to run outdated software and
> by extension it's dangerous to help somebody to remain on outdated
> software. It's something we should be militantly protective against. –
> [Oli♦](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)

Comment: What about issues (issues being some error, a weird message, etc.) of unanswered questions?

Comment: @Braiam elaborate and give examples?