# Non-EOL Notice: Quantal (12.10) remains supported through April 2014

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

Since 12.10 is non-LTS and 13.04 is non-LTS and 13.04 will be end-of-life in a week, it might seem like 12.10 must have been end-of-life a long time ago. **But that is not the case.** 12.10 is supported through April 2014.

- [Releases page.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)
- [12.10 release announcement with support information.](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-October/000164.html)

We have [at least one closed 12.10 question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407527/why-is-my-wireless-keyboard-logictech-v-r0002-always-functional-at-the-grub-me) where two close-voters voted to close with the EOL close reason. The question *also* appears to be an attempt to report a bug and I am *not* asking for it to be reopened.

However, this has alerted me to the need--equal to [the need to remind people about how 13.04 is about to be EOL](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8024/eol-notice-raring-13-04-will-be-end-of-life-on-january-27-2014)--to remind the community that **12.10 will not be EOL for another several months**.

(That one question is not my only source of information about people thinking 12.10 is already unsupported. I've heard this misconception expressed *many* times within the Ubuntu community.)

Anyone who sees a question that is closed, but *would not have been closed* if its close-voters knew 12.10 remains supported, should vote to reopen it. (The example I gave is almost certainly *not* such a question, of course.) If it turns out we have many of these, it would be appropriate to compile a list in a CW answer here. But my hope is that we do not and that, by issuing this reminder, I've helped prevent there ever being many.

---

Why is 12.10 supported so long and 13.04 supported so short? This is because of a recent policy change decreasing the length of time non-LTS releases are supported. The change occurred after 12.10 was released and does *not* apply retroactively. [This article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/ubuntu-to-halve-support-window-for-regular-releases) has more information.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty--which we do not *yet* support as it's in development--is [to be released](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) the same month that Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal goes EOL. So here's one way of remembering whether or not 12.10 is EOL: If a question about a problem in 12.10 is posted on the same day as a question about a problem in 14.04 LTS, and you'd vote to close the 14.04 question as being about Ubuntu+1, that most likely means the 14.04 question was posted too soon to (ever) be closed for being about 12.10.

More generally, [the releases wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) is always available to be consulted, whenever there's any question about whether or not a release is currently supported.

Comment: (blames the first voter D:)