# Do we really need EOL related announcements hanging about in the unanswered meta questions queue?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a couple of these: For example,

[EOL Notice: Precise Pangolin (12.04) will be End of Life starting April 28, 2017](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16823/eol-notice-precise-pangolin-12-04-will-be-end-of-life-starting-april-28-2017)

[Non-EOL Notice: Quantal (12.10) remains supported through April 2014](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8130/non-eol-notice-quantal-12-10-remains-supported-through-april-2014)

Since statements of fact are unlikely to result in much discussion and the EOL dates are published upon release at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases are notifications like this necessary?

Comment: A number of meta posts don't need any answer. An unanswered meta post is, depending on the contents of the post, no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Necessary? No.

Possibly helpful? Yes, as some members may not pay close attention to the schedule linked in the question. I do think it's important to re-iterate what I said [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15739/eol-notice-wily-werewolf-15-10-is-now-end-of-life-as-of-july-28-2016-enfo/15791#15791)