# Why have questions related to Ubuntu 13.04 been put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Moderators closed my question by substantiating that 13.04 exceeded LTS. As much as I know this site has nothing to do with official Ubuntu,  how come moderators here mention about exceeding LTS time. If I asked my question in `ubuntuforums.org` they could put forth reason of LTS to close my question. 
I want to know if this site has anything to do with official Ubuntu body, if so where can I ask questions related to 13.04?

Comment: and related http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8024/169736

Comment: It's not an answer, it means that moderators impose their decision over members of askubuntu. It's an antidemocratic decision. Why did you not put to vote your rule?

Comment: I actually agree with the moderator decision...

Comment: @Braiam
It's your choice not mine.

Comment: BTW, if you are talking about [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/422015/169736) the ones that closed your question were community members with close votes, no moderators. Also, you should read the question linked so you see the **community consensus**

Comment: I already criticize your `community consensus`

Comment: Give us a **very good reason** why we should change at least...

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Sometimes I need to ask questions about using an application or an error I meet. I don't ask any official bug fixing or application support. I also don't ask any moderator to answer my question. As the name of this site suggests I ask questions about Ubuntu, I haven't read somewhere on this site that only LTS questions can be answered. What about thousands of other users? Where they will ask questions about the problems they meet?

Comment: @kenn - please join us in the general chat-room to discuss. Thanks - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: @fossfreedom
:) thank you for invitation. Unfortunately I have a disability that prevents me typing longer. I hope my point gets understood. I hope you all change your decision about closing questions due to LTS criteria

Comment: @kenn - the only criteria is to use a supported version of Ubuntu.  At this moment this means 10.04 server/12.04/12.10 & 13.10.  13.04 reached EOL in Jan this year.

Comment: You can find out how this site is related to Ubuntu by clicking 'Ubuntu' at the top left - also [this](http://i.imgur.com/2u7V2rd.png) at the bottom of the [installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Comment: @fossfreedom - I can understand closing when it is a version specific problem, but if it isn't version specific, should it be closed? *(I may ask a question in future about this...)*

Comment: @Wilf - if a question applies to any ubuntu version then this is fine - but remember, to test if the question applies to any ubuntu version you really should be testing on a supported version first ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced that this site is an official affiliate  of  Ubuntu, so I respect its policy of LTS. Now that I'm not allowed here to ask questions about Ubuntu 13.04, I ll look for other forums.