# Could unanswered questions regarding EOL releases be removed via script?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

In my quest to clean up the [4000+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) **unanswered** questions with the blacklisted installation tag, I'm constantly running across unanswered questions regarding EOL releases like these:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/271868/ubuntu-12-10-problem-installer-stops-working

https://askubuntu.com/questions/296866/cannot-do-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-13-04-while-booting-from-dvd-soft-lockup-bu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/286330/ubuntu-13-04-installation-error

which I flag as **EOL** (when I raise this flag the system also raises the "can't be reproduced, was only valid for a short period of time flag")

As the close queues are constantly full (AFAIK, correct me if I'm wrong) wouldn't it be more effective to run a script to eliminate these unanswered questions regarding end of life distributions? Can this be considered?

Comment: The thing is, not all unanswered questions need to go.

Comment: Also, it is better to close old unanswered questions where the OP hasn't been seen in a long time as not-reproducible.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for your input. I agree that not all unanswered questions need to go, my question was regarding EOL releases. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Dunno why you're getting downvotes, I didn't downvote.

Comment: On meta downvotes just mean disagreement, and it doesn't affect rep.

Comment: @Seth All the more reason to clarify the question I think. I'm obviously not here for the rep. I don't think you earn the tenacious badge for being popular. ;-)

Comment: How about some comments? Down voting doesn't result in discussion. I'd like to understand your logic if you think this is a bad idea. Thank you!

Comment: If they weren't EOL when the question was asked - they should not get flagged or closed as EOL. Don't close/flag "ex post facto"

Comment: @Mateo this makes perfect sense for answered questions. Can you explain to us how an unanswered question regarding an EOL release is still useful? Is it preferable to simply fill the close queue with them? Or is it better to simply have 
54,181 questions with no upvoted answers?

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me.

Comment: If they are "not useful" they need to be closed with another reason, making them off topic retroactively is not something we should be doing.

Comment: @Mateo downvoting seems like The Best Thing To Do™

Comment: @Mateo when I flag a post EOL the system also raises the cannot be reproduced, solved itself or was only valid for a short period of time flag. (paraphrasing) This makes sense to me as this is especially true of unanswered EOL questions. If I know a problem isn't version specific I remove the invalid version tag. (as I assume we all do) It seems clear that we need more eyes on the posts than we have available.

Comment: @Briam if "downvoting seems like The Best Thing To Do™" would you care to help by downvoting some of the thousands of useless unanswered EOL questions tagged installation? After all a downvote only costs 1 point of rep. I won't get very far on the project without some help if I do it your way.

Comment: What is wrong with marking them off-topic? Whether a question is on-topic or not is a temporal judgement. A question may have been on topic when asked in the past, but the question is still open, and now it is off-topic. As for the suggestion to autoclose - judging by the close queue, most people are already marking these old questions as off-topic, so it wouldn't make that much difference if it were a bot doing the closing. Perhaps there should be a Launchpad-style bot that asks "Is this still a problem" and then auto-closes if it gets no response.

Comment: @bain I think your idea would go a long way toward improving the site. Questions that were posted over a year ago by drive-by and never returned to would then not waste the valuable time of the overworked and underpaid here. ;-)

Comment: There *is already a system for automatically taking care of old questions* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 and down-voting questions don't cost any rep.

Comment: Also I saw many in the queue that had little to do with the mentioned EOL release  - and were good questions! "Closing something because we (as a site) can't answer it just compounds one failure on top of another." - http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7153/47291

Comment: @Mateo The problem with the system in place in this instance is that many newer users will upvote a question to make a new user feel at home or simply because they don't know the answer themselves. I was guilty of this behaviour early on. It became clear that that behaviour was less than helpful. Many of the questions I'm talking about have been upvoted (by friends or the ignorant) already and are abandoned.  I can't speak to what's in the close queue although I'm responsible for the ones I flagged. I don't think there are questions we can't answer given the drive to do so.

Comment: I'm saying there is a lot in the review that were in there **just because they were tagged with 13.04**

Comment: um, no it dosn't... downvoting *Answers* costs rep - try it...

Comment: @Mateo Thanks. Misconception on my part.

Comment: Also this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6651/47291 especially the paragraph in all caps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that rather than voting to close/flagging, is more useful just to downvote it if the question has no future relevance (ie. installing EOL version of Ubuntu and having a problem) or that the version plays an important role (cue all the hardware problems).

What shouldn't? Well, things that doesn't matter what version of Ubuntu you have: create a desktop icon, or a launcher menu; changing the ordering of the entries at grub; installing a specific piece of software; summary, anything that doesn't need troubleshooting. That's a sane way to go.

Ah, bugs are still off topic, those should be closed nevertheless.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I thought downvotes were for bad questions/answers. It seems clear that EOL versions are OT or that wouldn't be an option for flagging. I thought that was also made quite clear here: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. It's not my intent to be abrasive, I'm just looking for logical solutions to obvious problems.

Comment: @ElderGeek but closing it wastes everyones' time, you need 5 users to close a question, and just 1 to delete an old post via downvote. There's even [a community manager](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1864878#1864878) that prefers that you downvote an old question so it gets deleted, rather than close it.